# Cursed earth from extra utilities does not spawn mobs

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have my custom minecraft **v1.6.4** mod pack with following mods: [full list](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AsJGELm4ir_edHNERWNGS1BZTEVaZUJ5XzhsMEprSEE&usp=sharing#gid=0). The thing is that I want to create mob spawner based on cursed earth: dark room with grinders from MFR and stuff. But the strange thing appeared to me - when I performed ritual to activate division sigil - no mobs were spawned... at all... after lightning stroke, cursed earth appeared but without any mobs. And when I prepared spawner, placed cursed earth and turned off the light - nothing happened. Room is completely dark but no mobs are spawning. I looked extra utilities config file, but found no settings to activate/deactivate/allow/disallow mob spawning on cursed earth. What could be the problem in?

P.S. Also the other issue is that cursed earth starts to burn with white lamp from project red 4 blocks above. In [this let's play](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4G_y-BdQ93M&noredirect=1) dw20 has 3 blocks of space between lamp and soil and everything is fine. I have Extra Utilities **v1.0.1**. Maybe should I just update it to newer version?

P.P.S. Well, I updated extra utilities to newest version (**1.0.3c**) at a time - it didn't help.

Comment: Are you in peaceful?

Comment: @Aaron128l, survival.

Comment: Any magnum torch or chandler from extra utilities to prevent anything from spawning?

Comment: @Aaron128l shouldn't matter, dw20 has a mag torch but mobs still spawned in his [mob trap](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4G_y-BdQ93M&noredirect=1)

Comment: @Aaron128l, I have nothing like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am experiencing the same issue. I am using single rows of cursed earth, so that might be the issue here. If you are using the same method, that might be the reason our farms are not working.
A screenshot of your farm design would help.

Edit: Alright scratch that. I just found the reason for my problem. I am using Mo'Creatures (which requires Custom Mob Spawner). CMS is not playing along nicely with the code of Cursed Earth and that is the reason for mobs not spawning on it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but then I removed the lamp and then it worked !!!